# Make only one button toggle on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

There are multiple buttons on page. When clicked, all buttons get triggered.

Make only one button, which is in the one that was clicked and in the same div with the

"Details" , trigger on click.

same buttons on page:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bttn > button').click(function() {
      $('.details').toggle("fast");

    });
  });
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bttn" style="text-align: center;"><button class="orange-button">Show details</button></div>`

<div>
  <p class="details" id="abc" style="text-align: center;color:grey;padding:1em;background-color:white;margin:5px;display:none;">info@thithi.com</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to assign an `id` on the button you want the details to appear from. Assign a `unique` to that and then forget about the other buttons.

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday as well - i had suggested the same thing i am not sure why you do not want give an `id` to that button.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've tried your suggestion and it didn't worked.There are same 10 buttons with same ID.

Comment: Id's must be unique for each. Its not a good practice in coding to use same `id` you will have alot of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this structure of html, should navigate like this and find the corresponding `.details`:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bttn > button').click(function() {
      // Changed Code
      $(this).parent().next().find('.details').toggle("fast");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bttn" style="text-align: center;"><button class="orange-button">Show details</button></div>`

<div>
  <p class="details" id="abc" style="text-align: center;color:grey;padding:1em;background-color:white;margin:5px;display:none;">info@thithi.com</p>
</div>
```